# I'm writing a program in Python that reads a csv file, then performs analysis on the data, but I can't generate any output

Tags: python, csv

The program collects the file name, starts the main() function, but doesn't return or print anything. I'm thinking my variables are not set correctly (global vs. local), but I've tried so many variations, my head is spinning. What am I doing wrong???

```
import os
import csv

inputdirectory = r'C:\...\python_challenge\Resources'
filename = input("Enter root file name here: " )
inputextension = input("Please type in the file extension: ")
csv_path = os.path.join("Resources", inputdirectory, "*." + filename + inputextension)
csvreader = csv.reader(filename, delimiter=",")
# Input section seems to work fine

def read_csv(csvreader):
    with open(csv_path) as filename:
        csvreader = csv.reader(filename, delimiter=",")
        next(csvreader, None)
        print(csvreader)
    return csvreader

def months(csvreader):
    for date in filename:
        date = list(csvreader)
    return date


def revenue(reader):
    total_revenue = 0
    for row in filename:
        total_revenue += int(row[1])
    return total_revenue


def main():
    reader = read_csv(filename)
    # this seems to be where program stalls - read_csv function does nothing 
    total_months = months(csvreader)
    dollar_summary = revenue(csvreader)
    print("Financial Analysis/n" + "-------------------------/n")
    print("Total Months: ", total_months)
    print("Total Revenue = $", dollar_summary)
    main()
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Have you tried debugging your program?

Comment: you never call `main()`, if you were referring to the last line of your code, it's calling it only within itself, remove the indentation on the last line, and it should work

Comment: In summary... simple typographical error. Downvote.

Comment: Thanks @N.Ivanov - simplest explanation, I guess. It opened up a whole new set of problems for another thread, but at least I'm moving forward.

Comment: thanks for the downvote @user202729?